# How to change the numbering style for enumeration and sub-enumeration

Tags: lists, enumerate

I wanted to use the `enumerate` environment. I am using this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To define the outliers and events.
            \begin{enumerate}
                        \item How can events be defined?
            \end{enumerate}
    \item To detect an event.
    \item To characterize an event.
    \item To evaluate the detected outliers and events.
\end{enumerate}
```

result:

1. To define the outliers and events.

   (a) How can events be defined?
2. To detect an event.
3. To characterize an event.
4. To evaluate the detected outliers and events.

I wanted to replace the sub numbering of alphabet with numbers.
Expected results:

1. To define the outliers and events.

   1.1 How can events be defined?
2. To detect an event.
3. To characterize an event.
4. To evaluate the detected outliers and events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use a specialized package such as `enumitem`, you could proceed by modifying the `\labelenumii` ("label of level-2 enum items") macro, as is done in the following MWE (minimum working example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To define the outliers and events.
            \begin{enumerate}
                        \item How can events be defined?
            \end{enumerate}
    \item To detect an event.
    \item To characterize an event.
    \item To evaluate the detected outliers and events.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that! That was me! I meant to *up*-vote it, but in my haste I must have pressed the down-vote arrow instead. Now, I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited :( @Mico

Answer (score 7):

Easy job with `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To define the outliers and events.
            \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}]        %% modified here
                        \item How can events be defined?
            \end{enumerate}
    \item To detect an event.
    \item To characterize an event.
    \item To evaluate the detected outliers and events.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As suggested by Werner, for internal enumeration, you can also use `label*={\arabic*}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item To define the outliers and events.
            \begin{enumerate}[label*={\arabic*}]        %% modified here
                        \item How can events be defined?
            \end{enumerate}
    \item To detect an event.
    \item To characterize an event.
    \item To evaluate the detected outliers and events.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the result is :  1. To dene the outliers and events.
[label=1.0]
(a) How can events be dened?
2. To detect an event.
3. To characterize an event.
4. To evaluate the detected outliers and events.

Comment: @aliamidi Can you post the code which gave you those results? Did you get it with my code?

Comment: Yes, I got it from your code.

Comment: @aliamidi Strange. but I got it right!